# How can I give a user in Fedora 14 the rights to write in a folder and all the sub-folders in it? 

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-14

My program needs to write in `/var/log` as well as `/usr/lib` including all the sub-folders in these directories.

How do I give permission for my program to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The only *safe* way of doing this would be to run your program as root. *Any* program that *needs* to write to system directories should be run as root anyway. A normal user has no business accessing those directories.

If your *really, really* want to make your system insecure you can look up SUID. Although, as explained [here](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=30), you will have trouble setting SUID for scripts.

I really do not recommend this though. Seriously, just run your program as root. On a debian derived system (or any other that has sudo configured) do:

```
$ sudo your_program_name
```

If sudo is not configured, do:

```
$ su
$ your_program_name
```